# Gradle DSL method not found 'android()' error?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new at developing android.I use Android Studio.I am getting an error Gradle DSL method not found:'android()'.Then I googled the error.Someone says that Android Studio incorrectly adds the android() method in the top-level build.gradle file. and delete the method.After I deleted android() from build.gradle.I am getting a new error Install Build Tools 23.0.0 rc2 and sync project.I am so tired with.

How can I overcome it.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

I can see you don't have the right Android plugin in your gradle file, it should be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Besides, you need the android extension to be something like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.package.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.5"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I think you are not editing the right Gradle file. You have a "general" build.gradle, which you should not edit generally, and your module build.gradle (typically in your app folder), where all these things need to be.

This is very similar to what you obtain by default when you create a new Android project.

Comment: After "upgrading" to Android Studio 1.5/1.5.1 I now get the same error and can no longer create an new project. Luckily my existing projects are okay.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading android studio, I always clean it by manually removing the `build/` and `app/build/` folders, and by building the project again.

Also: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`